# can't start ssh after upgrade ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, upstart

When upgrading my system crashed, and now I can not start the service ssh

```
root@elizium:/# stop ssh
stop: Unknown job: ssh
root@elizium:/# uname -a
Linux elizium 2.6.24-19-server #1 SMP Wed Jun 18 15:18:00 UTC 2008 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You are running `stop`, don't you mean start? Not sure about Ubuntu syntax but is it `service start ssh`? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-start-stop-ssh-server/

Answer (score 3):

run

```
service ssh start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Then verify if ssh runs or not by issuing command:

`netstat -ntlp` (which will show you sshd listening on port 22)